# TYPO3: submit a form

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm completely new to TYPO3. I've joined a project and I have some stuff to do.

I need to create a form and display it on the fronted. I've done this inside my ClassViewHelper (it's just a simple html form).

My coworker said that Typo3 have some common point with Symfony, but I don't see the MVC model (I don't have a controller associate with my ViewHelper).

So how do I submit a form ? Do I need to have a controller (I think so, this would be logic), or can I do it directly inside the ViewHelper ?

PS : I'm using 6.2.9 version, I think it's an old one but I have to keep it...

Comment: I suggest using the extension "form". It is a system (standard) extension. It is set up with a sort of array configuration. Has a few limitations, but if you need a simple form that is what i would use.

Comment: For 6.2 `ext:form` is the old version, which only can send a mail. Either use an extension from TER (powermail, formhandler, formz, ...) or do it yourself. Depending what you want to do (mail, record store, ...) multiple options are available.